# What does "son for a son" mean?

Tags: avatar-the-way-of-water

At the end of *Avatar The Way of Water* (2022) movie, Jake, who lost
his son Neteyam, hugs Spider and says:

> Jake: A **son for a son**.

What does "son for a son" mean?

Comment: Shouldn't this question be moved to the English Learners' Site? It got nothing to do with Sci-Fi or Fantasy apart from being used in a movie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, he says that because Colonel Quaritch has killed ("taken") Jake's son Neteyam.

In return, so to speak as a compensation **for that son**, Jake welcomes Quaritch's son Spider in his own family, thereby taking him away/receiving him from Quaritch.